# Connect 1GE SFP MM to 10GE SFP MM

Tags: switching, fiber, sfp

I have a situation in which the ISP can only accommodate a 1GE SFP and single mode fibre, but we have bought 10GE SFP.

Is it possible to get the physical link up when connecting a 1GE SFP to a 10GE SFP?

Assume both sides are multi mode or single mode.

Edit:
The testing methods are imperfect, but the results are in.
Connecting 10G-850MM-0.1km-MM-SFP+ to eSFP-GE-SX-MM850 fails.
Connecting 10G-850MM-0.1km-MM-SFP+ to 10G-850MM-0.1km-MM-SFP+ succeeds.

Comment: No, you need to get the correct device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the physical link up when connecting a 1GE SFP to a 10GE SFP?

Yes - under two conditions:

1. Both Ethernet variants need to use the same wavelength (e.g. 1310 nm for 1000BASE-**L**X/10GBASE-**L**R, or 850 nm for 1000BASE-**S**X/10GBASE-**S**R) and medium (SMF or MMF).
2. The 10G port and SFP(+) module must be compatible with the lower 1G speed - most ports are but very few transceivers ("dual rate") are. Explicit speed configuration for the interface is often required. Some 10G switches don't support dual-rate modules in general and require you to fit a 1G SFP module. Other switches might even link to 1G with a 10G module that isn't flagged for dual rate - mileage varies.

Answer (score 4):

1GE and 10GE use different frequency and encoding methods.  They are not compatible.

Comment: Is it possible to put a 10GE SFP in a 1GE interface an negotiate down to 1GE ?

Comment: It would depend on the SFP, but I've never seen one that does that.

Comment: @CaineKiewit A 10G SFP+ module doesn't work in a 1G SFP slot in general, unless the switch doesn't care (check) what you plug in at all.